# AdminData authentication suddently failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

in a Rails 2.3.6 I've been using for months AdminData with this code inside "initializers/admin_data_settings.rb":

```
AdminData::Config.set = {
  :is_allowed_to_view => lambda {|controller| controller.send('admin?') },
  :is_allowed_to_update => lambda {|controller| controller.send('admin?') }
}
```

Since yesterday, though, AdminData is allowing everybody to view and update data, even unauthorized users.

Of course I have a proper "admin?" method in application_controller but even:

```
AdminData::Config.set = {
  :is_allowed_to_view => false,
  :is_allowed_to_update => false
}
```

is allowing people to see/update data.

What can be causing this?

Thanks,
Augusto

Comment: What is the point of `controller.send('admin?')` compared to `controller.admin?` as they should be equivalent.

Comment: You are right, anyway it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with the AdminData add-on, it's probably a case of that authentication system not being engaged in that area.